# Access all table cell values by exposing an input$xxx_<something> selector (without having to use input$xxx_cell_click/select)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am developing an app where I display a (large) Markov transition matrix as a datatable, rendered client side. Of course, we can make this transition matrix editable for the user.

I would like to be able to:

- after the user edits some cells and then clicks an update button,
- to capture all values in all cells of this newly edited datatable (which was edited client side), and return it to R, say, as a matrix

I would then use these values to update a server side matrix/dataframe to now be these new values.

Here is a sample shiny app that might implement this:

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)


ui <- function(input, output, session) {

    fluidPage(
        textOutput('edit'),
        DTOutput('test'),
        actionButton('actbut', label = 'click')
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    rv <- reactiveValues( df = iris )

    output[['test']] <- renderDT({
        datatable(rv$df, editable = T)
    }, server = F)

    observeEvent(input$actbut, {
        # -- Suppose the user manually changes 
        # --all entries in df in the 
        # --Species column to "setosa", clientside.

        # -- I would like to be able to access the newly changed entries
        # -- using some attribute of input$test_<something>; 
        # -- in the same vein of input$test_cell_clicked, etc.
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(port = 5858))
```

If there is already an easy way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks to Yihui Xie for an incredible library.

Comment: Found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548785/r-shiny-datatable-with-numericinput-and-reactive-column.

It appears that there doesn't seem to be a reliable, stable solution.

I have decided to use `rhandsontable` package instead.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a stable/reliable solution, as per: [R shiny datatable with numericinput and reactive column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548785/r-shiny-datatable-with-numericinput-and-reactive-column)

Switching to using package `rhandsontable` for now. May file this as a feature request on DT github.